# Distributed web scraping framework 

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, web-crawler

What are the popular distributed web scraping framework out there?

Any with the REST interface support?

Which one is easier to host in AWS?

Which one does support web proxy use?

Is there anything on .NET?